# How can I use Google Drive Files inside a WebApp (PHP, Google APIs)

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm currently in the process of evaluating a platform that I'll have to develop and I'm wondering how much of this is possible using already existing libraries and such.

In short, I need to have users being able to add files to a **Google Drive account** created for the application (That part I've already figured out using the **Google_Service_Drive API** for the upload part.). Files will be either a **PDF or a Powerpoint Presentation (.ppt/.pptx)**. (I know that Google Drive uses Google Slides to read Powerpoint Presentation but that'll will come afterwards.)

I need to be able to **display the content uploaded by the users** on that same GDrive Account. So, if the user uploaded a .ppt/.pptx (which will be converted to a Slide Presentation), I need to "embed" it on the webpage, same for the PDF (I'll have to iframe the PDF itself as far as I'm aware).

Are those elements possible using the **Google Drive API** and the **Google Slides API**? Or would I need more than those 2 apis in order to fulfill the requirements? **Or is this not possible to 'read' the GDrive files outside of GDrive itself**?

Thanks.